# MD5 password fail in scapy based EAP-MD5 authentication scrtip

Tags: python, authentication, scapy

Now I'm programming EAP-MD5 authentication testing script based on scapy in my private network.

But, I've failed on 'response md5-challange' status with 'password fail'.

my script code is same below.  On this routine, parameter 'pkt' is from the requested MD5-Challange EAP packet

## ==========================================

```
 def response_md5_handler(pkt):
    global _PASSWD
    # .. skip .. 
    eth = pkt.getlayer(Ether)
    eap = pkt.getlayer(EAP)
    raw = pkt.getlayer(Raw)

    mypass = _PASSWD

    mychallegne =  str(eap.id) + mypass  + raw.load[1:] 
    resp = md5(mychallegne ).digest()
    resp = chr(len(resp)) + resp
    mypkt = _mk_eap_resp_md5(eth.dst, eap.id, resp )
    sendp(mypkt)
```

## ==========================================

Earlier stages(EAPOL start, Request Identity handling, Response Identity) are no problem and I've checked 'PASSWD' string.

Could you give some guide or tip? What is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution myself.
On below code,

```
mychallegne =  str(eap.id) + mypass  + raw.load[1:]
```

I've made mistake for 'eap.id' handling.
I should use  pack("!B", eap.id) insted of the str() function.